# AngularJS/Cordova battery status

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I'm trying to display the battery status of my device. I have installed the following plug-in:

`Cordova Cordova plugin add-plugin-battery status`

I have wrote a controller in a separate file named `batteryStatus.js`:

```
myApp.controller("BatteryCtrl", function($scope, $rootScope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaBatteryStatus) {

    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        $rootScope.$on("$cordovaBatteryStatus:status", function(result) {
            var batteryLevel = result.level;       // (0 - 100)
            var isPluggedIn  = result.isPlugged;   // bool
        });
    });
});
```

The call of the function from HTML:

`<script src="js/batteryStatus.js"></script>`

```
<div ng-controller="BatteryCtrl">
   Status: {{batteryLevel}} %
   Pluged In: {{isPluggedIn}}
</div>
```

But the status is not shown. What is wrong with the code?

**Edited Code:**

```
myApp.controller("BatteryCtrl", function($scope, $rootScope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaBatteryStatus) {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
            $rootScope.$on("$cordovaBatteryStatus:status", function(event, args) {
                console.log(args);
                $scope.batteryLevel = args.level;
                console.log($scope.batteryLevel);
                $scope.isPluggedIn = args.isPlugged;
                console.log($scope.isPluggedIn);        
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure your plugin has been added? It should be `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-battery-status`.

Comment: What if you do a `console.log(result);` in the terminal function there, e.g. on cordovaBatteryStatus, is it triggering?

Comment: I get no error output if I add `console.log(result);` nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uploaded a sample project in git hub for battery status in Ionic framework [battery-status](https://github.com/anilkumar007/Battery-Status) if you have any queries please let me know

Comment: My code is just like your code. But I have even deleted and added the Android platform. After that I added the Cordova  plugin `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-battery-status` back into the system. It worked. It must have somehow situated at the android platform. Now the status of battery is displayed  only when the app starts. How can I update the status always  throughout the whole session of the app? I use the HTML element  `<progress ng-controller="batteryController" max="100" value="{{batteryLevel}}"></progress>`  so that the state is always shown?

Comment: Yes, with the progress tag it is displaying the state of an battery continuously I checked it, having any queries please let me know @Ramosta

Comment: Thanks, but the status of the battery will not be updated, if I change the pages or open a new page. I have created a new post. Here you can read: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31963724/refreshing-the-battery-status-with-angularjs-ionic)

Comment: I have updated the code in github with your above requirement by adding bootstrap files.. please check it and update me if you have any conflicts in the requirement

Comment: @Ramosta, installing the plugin solved the problem .. greetings :)

Comment: @securecurve do you mean the plugin `cordova-plugin-battery-status`? The status of the battery is updated on each page? Do you have an example please?

Comment: @Ramosta, yes. For the example: the above code in the question is working

Comment: @securecurve I've posted the code above in the question. I uninstalled and installed the Plugin again. Unfortunately the status is shown only on the homepage. If I changed to a different page, the status will not be displayed or not updated. That ist my problem

Comment: I've edited the code in question. But that also doesn't update the battery status on different pages

Comment: @Ramosta, I'm not sure about your case, open a new question, and poke me here to try to help if I can

Comment: broadcast the batterystatus so that you will get the result on other pages @Ramosta

Answer (score 0):

```
controller("batteryController", function($scope, $rootScope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaBatteryStatus) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        $rootScope.$on("$cordovaBatteryStatus:status", function(event, args) {
            if(args.isPlugged) {
                alert("Charging -> " + args.level + "%");
            } else {
                alert("Battery -> " + args.level + "%");
            }
        });
    });
}
```

plug in and plug out cable, you will get the output :P