# Refreshing the battery status with AngularJS/Ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

My Ionic app displays the battery level in a HTML element `<progress></progress>`.

My problem is that **the status of the battery will not be updated**, if I change the pages or open a new page. In the case is the status always zero.

When I launch the app on the start page of the app looks the status like this (Now is fully charged):

[image]

when I change the pages so (the current status is not called):

[image]

My question is, **how can I update/refresh the status of the battery on every pages?**

The other question is, **how can I add the current percentage of the battery status in the `<progress>` Element**? like:

[image]

HTML:

```
<progress ng-controller="batteryController" max="100" value="{{batteryLevel}}">
</progress>
```

JavaScript:

```
myApp.controller("batteryController", function ($scope, $rootScope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaBatteryStatus) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        $rootScope.$on("$cordovaBatteryStatus:status", function (event, args) {
            console.log(args);
            $scope.batteryLevel = args.level;
            console.log($scope.batteryLevel);
            $scope.isPluggedIn = args.isPlugged;
            console.log($scope.isPluggedIn);           
        });
        $rootScope.$on('$cordovaBatteryStatus:critical', function (event, args) {
            $scope.batteryLevel = args.level;       // (0 - 100)
            $scope.isPluggedIn  = args.isPlugged;   // bool
        });

        $rootScope.$on('$cordovaBatteryStatus:low', function (event, args) {
            $scope.batteryLevel = args.level;       // (0 - 100)
            $scope.isPluggedIn  = args.isPlugged;   // bool
        });
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
/* All HTML5 progress enabled browsers */
progress {

    /* Turns off styling - not usually needed, but good to know. */
    appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    /* gets rid of default border in Firefox and Opera. */
    border: solid #cccccc 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    /* Dimensions */
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
}

/* Polyfill */
progress[role]:after {
    background-image: none; /* removes default background from polyfill */
}

/*
 * Background of the progress bar background
 */

/* Firefox and Polyfill */
progress {
    background: #cccccc !important; /* !important only needed in polyfill */
}

/* Chrome */
progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
    background: #cccccc;
}

/*
 * Background of the progress bar value
 */

/* Firefox */
progress::-moz-progress-bar {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
            center bottom,
            rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
            rgb(84,240,84) 69%
    );
}

/* Chrome */
progress::-webkit-progress-value {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
            linear,
            left bottom,
            left top,
            color-stop(0, rgb(43,194,83)),
            color-stop(1, rgb(84,240,84))
    );
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(
            center bottom,
            rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
            rgb(84,240,84) 69%
    );
}

/* Polyfill */
progress[aria-valuenow]:before {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
            center bottom,
            rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
            rgb(84,240,84) 69%
    );
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(
            center bottom,
            rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
            rgb(84,240,84) 69%
    );
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(
            center bottom,
            rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
            rgb(84,240,84) 69%
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a simple solution for this.First add a plugin battery-status

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-battery-status
```

**Javascript**

```
myApp.controller('batteryController', function($scope,$ionicPlatform) {

   $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
            window.addEventListener("batterystatus", onBatteryStatus, false);

            function onBatteryStatus(info) {
                info.level;
                percentageChanged(info.level);

            }
        });

        function percentageChanged(value) {
            $scope.batteryLevel = value;
        };
```

});

This batterystatus event fires when the percentage of battery charge changes by at least 1 percent, or if the device is plugged in or unplugged.So we can update the value of batteryLevel by angular two way binding syntax.

**Html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Menu">
    <ion-content class="padding">
        <div style="position: absolute;text-align: center;width: 100%;padding: 13px;">{{batteryLevel}}%
        </div>
        <progress max="100" value="{{batteryLevel}}">100
        </progress>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

The percentage can shown in your progress bar by adding an extra div tag.

Comment: The status will be displayed but will not be updated if I change the pages. My problem is not displaying the status but rather updating the status. I still could not solve the problem.

Comment: @Ramosta be aware that this can be very battery intensive / draining. More information here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-battery-status